# Convert a Generic List to specific type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List which contains some values.

**Example:**

```
List<object> testData = new List <object>();
testData.Add(new List<object> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" });
testData.Add(new List<object> { "ddd", "eee", "fff" });
testData.Add(new List<object> { "ggg", "hhh", "iii" });
```

And I have a class like

```
class TestClass
{
    public string AAA {get;set;}
    public string BBB {get;set;}
    public string CCC {get;set;}
}
```

How to convert the `testData` to the type `List<TestClass>` ?

Is there a way to convert other than this?

```
testData.Select(x => new TestClass()
{
   AAA = (string)x[0],
   BBB = (string)x[1],
   CCC = (string)x[2]
}).ToList();
```

I don't want to mention the column names, so that I can use this code irrespective of class changes.

I also have a `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` which has the data.

Comment: I suppose I have to ask: why are you working all in Object?

Comment: WRT the edit: No, not with a List, if you have a Dictionary, then yes :)

Comment: @leppie Yes I also have a dictionary. Can you please tell me the code.

Comment: @RameshDurai: Search on StackOverflow, I am sure many has asked that. OR use the `JavaScriptSerializer` if you are not worried about speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to explicitly create the TestClass objects, and moreover cast the outer objects to `List<object>` and the inner objects to strings.

```
testData.Cast<List<object>>().Select(x => new TestClass() {AAA = (string)x[0], BBB = (string)x[1], CCC = (string)x[2]}).ToList()
```

You could also create a constructor in TestClass that takes `List<object>` and does the dirty work for you:

```
public TestClass(List<object> l)
{
    this.AAA = (string)l[0];
    //...
}
```

Then:

```
testData.Cast<List<object>>().Select(x => new TestClass(x)).ToList()
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert without specifying the fieldNames in the class (ex: AAA = (string)x[0])

Comment: Constructor, as @lc. mentions.

Comment: See my edit. Can you help me now with the code? I also have an IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> object. (IEnumerable<Dictionary<columnname, value>>)

Comment: That's a completely different question. Yes, but you'll either have to use reflection or give the TestClass a string indexer

Comment: Thanks @Fuex. I'm on my phone and I can't see how many spaces I have.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
var res = testData
    .Cast<List<object>>() // Cast objects inside the outer List<object>
    .Select(list => new TestClass {
        AAA = (string)list[0]
    ,   BBB = (string)list[1]
    ,   CCC = (string)list[2]
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Linq is your friend:

```
var testList = testData
                  .OfType<List<object>>()
                  .Select(d=> new TestClass
                                  {
                                     AAA = d[0].ToString(), 
                                     BBB = d[1].ToString(), 
                                     CCC = d[2].ToString()})
                  .ToList();
```

**EDIT:** For the `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>`, and without hard-coding field names in the Linq statement, I would simply pass each Dictionary to the constructor of the object to be instantiated, and have the object try to hydrate itself using the field names it knows about:

```
var testList = testData
                  .OfType<Dictionary<string,object>>()
                  .Select(d=> new TestClass(d))
                  .ToList();

...

class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(Dictionary<string,object> data)
    {
        if(!data.ContainsKey("AAA")) 
           throw new ArgumentException("Key for field AAA does not exist.");
        AAA = data["AAA"].ToString();

        if(!data.ContainsKey("BBB")) 
           throw new ArgumentException("Key for field BBB does not exist.");
        BBB = data["BBB"].ToString();

        if(!data.ContainsKey("CCC")) 
           throw new ArgumentException("Key for field CCC does not exist.");
        CCC = data["CCC"].ToString();
    }

    public string AAA {get;set;}
    public string BBB {get;set;}
    public string CCC {get;set;}
}
```

The constructor can use a reflective loop to get its type's list of fields, then get those KVPs out of the Dictionary and set them to the current instance. That would make it slower, but the code would be more compact which might be a concern if TestClass actually has a dozen fields instead of three. The basic idea remains unchanged; give the data needed to hydrate a TestClass to the TestClass, in the form you have it in, and let the class constructor figure out what to do with it. Understand that this WILL throw an exception on the first error creating any of the TestClass objects.

Comment: Wont compile for 2 reasons ;p

Comment: Still wont compile for 1 reason ;p Edit: Second cast is not needed.

Comment: Nope, it's Friday afternoon, you are forgiven, but there is still a subtle error ;p Edit: Not that one either, I missed that ;p

Comment: @leppie wow haven't heard that sound in forever, but reading your comment my brain played it back nicely :)