# How to Cast List<T> To List<ClassName>

Tags: c#, generics

I am using generic method to fill my dropdown for all types

below is my code.

the entity type are as follow

```
public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DropDown
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

i am able to fetch data successfully at
`var data = DataFetcher.FetchData<T>();`

```
private static void Main( string[] args )
{
    List<DropDown> cities = BLL.GetDataList<City>();
    List<DropDown> states = BLL.GetDataList<State>();
    List<DropDown> roles = BLL.GetDataList<Role>();
}

public static class BLL
{
    public static List<DropDown> GetDataList<T>() where T : class ,new()
    {
        var data = DataFetcher.FetchData<T>();
        return data as List<DropDown>;
    }
}
```

I knew this cast `data as List<DropDown>` will fail,thats why its returning null back to calling method,

How can i cast Generic list to List of Known Type?

Comment: You have to ask yourself: how do I want to convert `T` to `DropDown`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Generic List to specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426426/convert-a-generic-list-to-specific-type)

Comment: How are `Role`, `State`, and `City` related to `DropDown`?

Comment: What does `FetchData` actually return? Is it convertible to `DropDown`? Perhaps you want to populate the `DropDown` with the data, instead of trying to convert it.

Comment: And why do you have your own `DropDown` type, aren't you using an UI framework?

Comment: Why are you using two different objects with the exact same properties? Is there any good reason for that?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Actually its an replica of my needin console application... Role is something that is only available till DataAcesslayer, but the dropdown will persist to web ...

Comment: I am now wondering whether all SO user abide the guidelines for downvoting !!

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask yourself: how do I want to convert `T` to `DropDown`? If you can't answer this, the answer is: you can't.

I *guess* your `DropDown` class has an `object Value` property, that holds the dropdown value, and you wish to assign the data entity to that property.

Then you can project the list of data entities to `DropDown`s as such:

```
var data = DataFetcher.FetchData<T>();
return data.Select(d => new DropDown { Value = d }).ToList();
```

As for your edit: so you have at least one type, the displayed `Role`, that has an `Id` and `Name` property. But type `T` doesn't guarantee this, so you'd need to introduce an interface:

```
public interface INamedIdentifyableEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And apply this to your entities. Then introduce it as a generic constraint and do the mapping:

```
return data.Select(d => new DropDown
{ 
    Id = d.Id,
    Name = d.Name,
}).ToList();
```

But you don't want this, as here you are tying these two properties to dropdowns. Tomorrow you'll want an entity with `Code` instead of `Id` and `Text` instead of `Name`, so you'll have to add more interfaces, more overloads, and so on.

Instead you might want to use reflection, where you can specify the member names in the call:

```
List<DropDown> cities = BLL.GetDataList<City>(valueMember: c => c.CityCode, displayMember: c => c.FullCityname);
```

And use these member expressions to look up `data`'s values and fill those into the `DropDown`.

However, you're then reinventing the wheel. Leave out your `DropDown` class entirely, and leave the dropdown generation to the front end, in this case MVC:

```
var cities = DataFetcher.FetchData<City>();

var selectList = new SelectList(cities.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Selected = (c.Id == selectedCityId),
    Text = c.FullCityName,
    Value = c.CityCode,
});
```

Or:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(cities, "CityCode" , "FullCityName", selectedCityId);
```

Comment: i dont have `object value` ,edited the question please look

Comment: Thanks ,your answer not exactly solved my problem but indeed it  helped me to get insight of my own problem, Nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

First create a map between your models like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Role, DropDown>();
```

Do the same thing for `City` and `State` classes if you need to.

Then you can use AutpMapper to convert your objects to `DropDown` like this:

```
public static List<DropDown> GetDataList<T>() where T : class ,new()
{
    var data = DataFetcher.FetchData<T>();
    return data.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DropDown>(x)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, Automapper can map collections directly; something like  `Mapper.Map<List<DropDown>>(DataFetcher.FetchData<T>())` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you could use Linq as follows.

```
return data.Cast<DropDown>().ToList();
```

Comment: That only works if a cast from `T` to `DropDown` exists.